# php regex: removing more than double space

Tags: php, regex

```
$tags = preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ', $tags);
```

that will remove more than just one space ?

i need to remove anything more than double space.

Comment: silly me....please delete this question

Comment: What do you mean by remove anything more than double space? Do you want to make three spaces to two spaces? Or one space? Or remove all three spaces?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm taking "more than double space" to mean 3 or more spaces:

```
$tags = preg_replace('/\s{3,}/',' ', $tags);
```

This will replace 3 or more contiguous occurrences of any whitespace character with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to replace a sequence of 2 or more spaces with a single space? What you've got there is pretty much it, except that it will match any whitespace (tabs, etc) not just spaces.