# PHP and str_replace with a regex (delete more than one successive whitespace)

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex: removing more than double space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277053/php-regex-removing-more-than-double-space)

I have a string like this one:

```
$a = "aaa    bbb";
```

And I would like to delete any successive whitespace (if there is more than one whitespace somewhere, it should be deleted).

So, the $a will become

```
 "aaa bbb".
```

I have tryed with:

```
$a = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/g","",$a);
```

And also

```
$a = preg_replace("\s{2,}","",$a);
```

But I am getting allways a null.

Any idea, thank you.

Comment: try this: preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$input). thanks to ghostdog74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$a = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ",$a);
```

Replace every whitespace more than one with one.

Comment: My answer was actually before Jason, he didn't put a whitespace in the second argument.

Comment: Happy? :-) I checked your answer.

Comment: You can also +1 my question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/',' ',$a);
```

`g` is not a [valid modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). It is implied. Also you want to replace multiple spaces with a single space.

**Note:** This will not replace single *whitespace* characters. Consider this for a tab or new line.

Comment: Thank you @Jason, By trying your solution, I am getting the same string, after doing the preg_replace...

Comment: It works for me. If it doesn't for you, something else is wrong.

Comment: I really don't know, I am doing a basic think. I have a string and then preg_replace this string and nothing hapens.

Comment: Ok, I sow the problem, my ehitespaces are &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and see

```
$a = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $a);
```

hope it might help you i have tested it and its working